# Python- Group by column by selecting first value from another column, but not if value was already chosen

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:

```
Tag  Class  
A    P      
A    Q
B    P      
B    Q     
C    P      
C    Q    
C    R
```

I want to group by Tag and keep the first value from Class. However, if this value was used previously, look for the next value within the tag.

Expected output:

```
Tag  Class  
A    P      
B    Q        
C    R
```

If there is no class left for the tag, then return null (or don't include Tag in output).

I have been trying to do this with drop_duplicates, but with no luck. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can define a custom function lets call it `dedupe`, which maintains an internal state in a `set` variable `s` to keep track of the previously used classes and returns the first available class for each group which is previously not used

```
def dedupe():
    s = set()
    def _dedupe(c):
        c = c[~c.isin(s)]
        if len(c) > 0:
            s.add(c.iat[0])
            return c.iat[0]
    return _dedupe


df.groupby('Tag', sort=False, as_index=False)['Class'].apply(dedupe())
```

---

```
  Tag Class
0   A     P
1   B     Q
2   C     R
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I return class as well in the output? Currently it only seems to return Tag

Comment: @TheloniousMonk This result will contain `Tag` as well as `Class`. Check the output of `df.groupby('Tag', as_index=False)['Class'].apply(dedupe())`

Comment: I checked once again, it is only returning Tag and not Class

Comment: I guess the problem seems to be with the parameter `as_index=False` in old version of **pandas**, to fix this use `reset_index`. Check with `df.groupby('id', sort=False)['vin'].apply(dedupe()).reset_index()`